# Хранение структурированных данных, введённых с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

Доброй ночи друзья! Язык C++ я не знаю, но подруге очень хочу помочь, вот и стал ковыряться. Ей дали задание :

описать структуру с именем znak, содержащую следующие поля:

- фамилия, имя;
- знак зодиака;
- дата рождения (массив из трех чисел)

написать программу, выполняющую след. действия:

-ввод с клавиатуры данных в массив, состоящий из восьми элементов типа znak;

записи должны быть упорядочены по датам рождения;

Я бы конечно начал учить язык по-нормальному, приобрёл бы несколько книжек рекомендованных вами, но результат нужен уже завтра утром, и вот что я надумал, но не могу нормально записать **AddThey** в массив **People** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
//
int PeopleCounter;
//
struct znak {
    int id;
    string LastName;
    string FirstName;
    string Sign;
    int Day;
    int Month;
    int Year;
};
//
znak People[];
//
string ReceiveAData() {
    string content;
    string line;
    //
    do {
        getline(cin, line);
        content += line + '\n';
    } while (!line.empty());
    //
    return content;
}
//
int AddThis() {
    znak AddThey;
    //
    AddThey.id          =   PeopleCounter + 1;
    cout << "Введите фамилию :" << endl;
    AddThey.LastName    =   ReceiveAData();
    //
    cout << "Введите имя :" << endl;
    AddThey.FirstName   =   ReceiveAData();
    //
    cout << "Введите знак зодиака :" << endl;
    AddThey.Sign        =   ReceiveAData();
    //
    cout << "Укажите день(1-31) рождения :" << endl;
    AddThey.Day         =   stoi(ReceiveAData());
    //
    cout << "Укажите месяц(1-12) рождения :" << endl;
    AddThey.Month       =   stoi(ReceiveAData());
    //
    cout << "Укажите год(4 числа) рождения :" << endl;
    AddThey.Year        =   stoi(ReceiveAData());
    //
    People[PeopleCounter]   =   AddThey;
    PeopleCounter++;
    //
    return 1;
}
//
int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Стартанули, выберите задачу :" << endl << endl;
    cout << "1 Ввести данные" << endl;
    cout << "2 Вывести список введённого" << endl;
    //
    if (_getch() == '1'){
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Режим ввода данных" << endl << endl;
        AddThis();
        //
        cout << PeopleCounter;
    }
    //
    _getch();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Завтра утром, это уже 10-го?

Comment: avp, да, завтра утром

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите, подойдет ли подруге?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct znak {
  string fname, lname, zname;
  int id, day, mon, year;
};

static inline bool check_date (znak *p)
{
  if (p->day < 1 || p->day > 31)
    return false;
  if (p->mon < 1 || p-> mon > 12)
    return false;
  if (p->year < 1900 || p->year > 2014)
    return false;
  return true;
}

// функция читает очередную структуру и увеличивает id 
// возвращаем 0 при EOF (в консоли ^D или ^Z в винде)
znak *
get_pdata (int *curid)  // Глобальные переменные это нехорошо. Постараемся все делать через параметры функций
{
  static znak p;  // Это область памяти, адрес которой возвращаем. В main данные будут копироваться в вектор
  /* Обратите внимание на static перед структурой. Это важно! 
     Память выделяемая таким образом сохраняется неизменной между вызовами функции.
     Таким образом данные могут быть простым способом возвращены в вызывающую процедуру.
     Тут, конечно, минус. Последние введенные strings в структуре останутся в памяти до конца всего процесса.
  */

  do { // будем читать в цикле, пока не введут все правильно
    cout << "Enter: first & last names, zodiac, day, month, year: ";
    cin >> p.fname >> p.lname >> p.zname >> p.day >> p.mon >> p.year;    
    if (cin.good()) {
      if (check_date(&p))
        break;
      cout << "Invalid date format (1-31, 1-12, 1900-2014) repeate...\n";
      continue;
    }
    if (cin.eof()) {
      cout << "\nEnd of input\n";
      return 0;
    } else {
      string errline;
      // Похоже, что вместо чисел в дате вводились буквы. 
      // Обязательно надо убрать их из потока ввода.
      getline(cin, errline); // проще всего прочесть их вместе с остатком строки
      cin.clear(); // и сообщить крестам о том, что мы исправили ситуацию
      cout << "Bad input. Try again...\n";
    }
  } while (1);

  p.id = ++(*curid); // увеличим "глобальный id" и присвоим его текущей персоне
  return &p;
}

static void
print_p (vector<znak> p)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++)
    cout << p[i].id << ":\t" << p[i].fname << " " << p[i].lname << " ("
         << p[i].zname << ")\t"
         << p[i].day << '/' << p[i].mon << '/' << p[i].year << '\n';
}

// функция компаратор 2-х дат для крестовой сортировки
static bool cmp_date_p (znak p1, znak p2)
{
  int d = p1.year - p2.year;
  if (d)
    return d < 0;
  if (d = p1.mon - p2.mon)
    return d < 0;
  return p1.day < p2.day;
}

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  vector<znak> p; // здесь запоминаем все структуры по мере их ввода
  znak *per;      // адрес только-что введенных данных
  int curid = 0;

  while (per = get_pdata(&curid)) {
    p.push_back(*per); // добавим очередную персону
  }

  cout <<  p.size() << " persons loaded\n";
  print_p(p);
  sort(p.begin(), p.end(), cmp_date_p); // это встроенная сортировка из <algorithms>

  cout <<  p.size() << " persons sorted\n";
  print_p(p);

}
```

Я не издеваюсь, просто короче не получилось... В принципе `static` и `inline` в описаниях функций можно и убрать (чтобы меньше было вопросов).

Компилировал в линуксе.

Если что-то совсем непонятно, то спрашивайте.

Comment: Разберёмся, благодарю)

Answer (score 2):

С\С++ низкоуровневый язык, потому при создании массива нужно сразу указать размер и этот размер должен быть const на момент компиляции, так же размер массива нельзя будет изменить.

если выделять массив в динамической памяти (через new) то можно указывать не const размер и размер такого массива можно будет изменять (создавая новый массив и копирую туда данные из старого).

советую заглянуть вот сюда [http://www.cplusplus.com/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/) и приглядеться к контейнерам set,vector,map так как они будут за вас работать с памятью.
однако при "сдаче" нужно будет объяснить "что это такое" хотя бы в двух словах